# 'int' object is not subscriptable yet all associated variables are fine

Tags: python, syntax

I seem to have a line of code with an object not subscribable fault but all items in the equate check out individually.  The equation that gives me the problem is this

```
oRetVal['Assay'] = tRS2[oCSNo_dx[aRow[oFields_dx['CycleRef']]][oFields_dx['Assay']]]
```

- tRS2 = a recordset returned from an sqlite database as a tuple
- oCSNo_dx = an object used as an index
- aRow = an array of values representing a single row from a db table
- oFields_dx = another object used as an index

On the lines immediately prior to this error line I run the following tests.

```
print(oCSNo_dx[aRow[oFields_dx['CycleRef']]])   # get 1
print(oFields_dx['Assay'])                      # get 21
print(tRS2[1][21])                              # get 0.0
print(tRS2[1])                                  # get single recordset (correct one) as expected
print(tRS2[oCSNo_dx[aRow[oFields_dx['CycleRef']]]][oFields_dx['Assay']])   # get 0.0
oRetVal['Assay']=0.0                  # No Fault
oRetVal['Assay']=tRS2[1][21]          # No fault     
print(oRetVal['Assay'])                           # get 0.0
```

From the tests oRetVal['Assay'] should take the value 0.0 from tRS2[1][21] in the full equation but it gives me the error.  Just to be sure I ran the following and no error was raised ..

```
s = oCSNo_dx[aRow[oFields_dx['CycleRef']]]
p = oFields_dx['Assay'] 
oRetVal['Assay']=tRS2[s][p]
```

I have gone with this for now but I would dearly like to know why I couldn't do the one liner in case this is a syntax thing and I come across it again.  Idea's anyone?

Comment: Counting `]` from your equation: 3 at the end. In your tests: never 3 at the end. That should be the hint leading you to Daniel Rosemans answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your square brackets are in the wrong place. You're not looking up `tRS2[1][21]`, but `tRS2[1[21]]`, hence the error. It should be:

```
tRS2[oCSNo_dx[aRow[oFields_dx['CycleRef']]]][oFields_dx['Assay']]
```

But really, don't do it like this; it's impossible to debug, as you have found. Set some intermediate variables and use them in the lookup.

Comment: `1[21]`? What is this magic?

Comment: @obskyr it is the source of the error OP is getting

Comment: @obskyr: the result of a misplaced `]` bracket. Their debugging attempt with `print` placed the brackets correctly.

Comment: @ChristianKönig Oh, hahah, I figured it was nonsense.

Comment: I will take your advice to heart.  Thank you Daniel.